# Get value from promise object (serverside) into client-side index.html

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise

I would like to know how to convert an promise object into a string.
I am calling to an API which returns a XML object, using axios and transform for templating. My application is using Express as an application skeleton. I have a console.log in the .then from the promise, which returns the data in the console in the command line.

However when I want to progress this data in my index.html, I'm getting a promise object back in the console. How would I be able to get the 'cover' part of the data from the promise object into my index.html?

Server console logging:
[image]

Console logging in browser:
[image]

***Project files:***

**./routes/index.js**

```
router.get('/metadata', function(req,res,next){
    var info = metadata.getMetadataOnix(params);
    console.log('info:'+info);
    res.json({ test : info });
});
```

**index.html which contains a ajax get which get calls on document.ready**

```
 $.get("/metadata", function(data){
      // call to metadata
});
```

**metadata-onix.js - file where I call an api**

```
const axios = require('axios');
const transform = require('camaro');

exports.getMetadataOnix = function (id) {
    const template = {
        uitgever: '/Product/PublishingDetail/Publisher/PublisherName/text()',
        cover: "./Product/CollateralDetail/SupportingResource[ResourceContentType=01]/ResourceVersion/ResourceLink/text()"
    }

    return axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: 'https://someapi/getMetadataOnix/'+id,
        transformResponse: [function (data) {
            "use strict";
            data = transform(data, template);
            return data;
        }],
    }).catch(function(err){
        // log errors
        console.log('error:'+err);
    }).then(function(resp){
        var cover = '';
        cover = resp.data.cover;
        console.log('Cover from book:'+JSON.stringify(resp.data.cover));
        return cover;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few problems there. The main one related to your question is that you're using the result of `getMetadataOnix` incorrectly. It returns a **promise**, so you have to use that promise. One way is via `then`:

```
router.get('/metadata', function(req,res,next){
    var info = metadata.getMetadataOnix('9789024576791').then(function(info) {
        console.log('info:'+info);
        res.json({ test : info });
    });
});
```

Don't worry about the fact that means that your `get` callback returns before you send your response; that's not a problem, Express is designed for that.

Separately, two issues around error handling:

First, you're converting a *rejection* into a resolution with/`undefined` here:

```
exports.getMetadataOnix = function (id) {
    // ...

    return axios({
        // ...
    }).catch(function(err){           // <===
        // log errors                 // <===
        console.log('error:'+err);    // <===
    }).then(function(resp){
        var cover = '';
        cover = resp.data.cover;
        console.log('Cover from book:'+JSON.stringify(resp.data.cover));
        return cover;
    });
}
```

Remember that `then` and `catch` create handler chains, where each step in the chain transforms the value passing through it. By putting that `.catch` where you have, you convert rejection into a resolution with whatever value you return from the `catch` handler. Since you don't explicitly return one, it ends up being `undefined`.

Since your `then` handler doesn't check for that, it'll throw an error when you try to use `resp.data.cover` in it, because `resp` will be `undefined`. Amusingly, that converts the resolution back into a rejection (one that is never handled).

Instead, don't handle errors there at all. One of the rules of promises is that you *either* return the promise chain to the caller, *or* handle errors, but not both. (You might convert an error to another kind of error, but you don't convert it to a resolution unless you can actually fix the problem.)

Handle it in your `get` callback instead. So:

```
exports.getMetadataOnix = function (id) {
    const template = {
        uitgever: '/Product/PublishingDetail/Publisher/PublisherName/text()',
        cover: "./Product/CollateralDetail/SupportingResource[ResourceContentType=01]/ResourceVersion/ResourceLink/text()"
    }

    return axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: 'https://someapi/getMetadataOnix/'+id,
        transformResponse: [function (data) {
            "use strict";
            data = transform(data, template);
            return data;
        }],
    // No .catch here
    }).then(function(resp){
        var cover = '';
        cover = resp.data.cover;
        console.log('Cover from book:'+JSON.stringify(resp.data.cover));
        return cover;
    });
}
```

and

```
router.get('/metadata', function(req,res,next){
    var info = metadata.getMetadataOnix(params)
        .then(function(info) {
            console.log('info:'+info);
            res.json({ test : info });
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            // Log error, etc.
            // Use `res.send` or `res.json` or similar to send error reply
        });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, I'll be implementing this. I'll let you know if it works.

Comment: Thanks so much! You're a lifesaver :)